# Using Jinja2 MemcachedBytecodeCache With Django

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I apologize if this answer is obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to enable Jinja2's MemcachedBytecodeCache in Django (I'm using version 3.0, but generally either).  [Jinja's documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.Environment) makes it sound like it a relatively straightforward setting:

> class jinja2.MemcachedBytecodeCache(client, prefix='jinja2/bytecode/', timeout=None, ignore_memcache_errors=True)
>
> This class implements a bytecode cache that uses a memcache cache for storing the information. It does not enforce a specific memcache library (tummy’s memcache or cmemcache) but will accept any class that provides the minimal interface required.

The goal, obviously, is to enable Jinja's bytecode caching with Memcached, which is already enabled on my site. Any assistance in implementing this in settings would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To use a bytecode cache, instantiate it and pass it to the Environment:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from jinja2 import Environment, MemcachedBytecodeCache

def environment(**options):
    bcc = MemcachedBytecodeCache(cache._cache, prefix='jinja2_bytecode_', timeout=3600, ignore_memcache_errors=True)
    env = Environment(trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True, bytecode_cache=bcc, **options)
    return env
```

Put this code in jinja2_setup.py in your base directory and instantiate the Environment in your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
     'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jinja2'), ],
     'APP_DIRS': True,
     'OPTIONS': {'environment': "jinja2_setup.environment", }
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you provide more context as to how this works? E.g. how is environment() called, where does this code live?